# Google spreadsheet script to add two cells together

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two columns with numbers in them. I need a script I can call via menu to add these two columns, and then clear the value in the first.  I have been unable to locate any examples on how to do this, so I don't have any attempted code.

Example:

```
 D12  E12
 10   26
```

I would like a script that would change E12 to 36, then clear cell D12.

Comment: how do you choose what cells to process ? is it always the same couple of columns ? you need to give more details and it would also be a good idea to show what you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use getRange() http://goo.gl/vDqrA

I think this should do it.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("D12").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("E12").getValue();
ss.getRange("E12").setValue(num1+num2);
ss.getRange("D12").clear();
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great...now I just need to figure out how to put the function into a menu option, I'm sure that is around here somewhere...Thanks for the help!