# This Google Apps script formats *typed* text properly, but does not format *pasted* text at all

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For example, if I were to **type** "cucumber" into B6 then it would be formatted with foo.com/cucumber in the following sheet...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1usCU2UutcC9jchLlM-oBZVqgdfw_ERNFjOfrU_t5hkc/edit#gid=2100307022

That is what I want.

But if I were to **paste** "cucumber" into B6 then it would **not** be formatted with foo.com/cucumber

I want to be able to **paste** in text—such as "abc"—into column B and have it formatted with foo.com/abc.

Here's the code...

```
function onEdit(e){
  urlMaker(e);
}

function urlMaker(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!= 'Sheet1' || e.range.rowStart <2 || e.range.columnStart !=2){return}
  e.range.setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(e.value).setLinkUrl('http://###.com/'+e.value).build());
}
```

I found the following, but it doesn't look like it would do what I want.

[how to apply script to entire columns in google spredsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265937/how-to-apply-script-to-entire-columns-in-google-spredsheet)

Pasting a value into the column results in the following error in the execution log:

```
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setText on object SpreadsheetApp.RichTextValueBuilder.
    at urlMaker(Code:7:62)
    at onEdit(Code:2:3)
```

Comment: Directly include the code in your question, while also adding a link to the source and crediting the author as per Creative Commons license requirements(CC by NC 4/3)

Comment: @Tiel From `I'm not interested in working with you on this issue.`, although I would like to have supported you, unfortunately, I understood it. This is due to my poor skill and my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would like to study more and more. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill and my poor English skill. And, I have to delete my answer.

Comment: Please relax Tanaike. You don't need to apologize. I appreciate your sincere effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason when you paste a value into a cell, `e.value` is `undefined`.

You can get it working by swapping `e.value` to `e.range.getValue()` though:

```
function onEdit(e){
  urlMaker(e);
    console.log(e.range)
}

function urlMaker(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!= 'Sheet1' || e.range.rowStart <2 || e.range.columnStart !=2){
    return
  }
    const RTV = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    const values = e.range.getValues()
    const rtvs = []

    values.forEach(function(row) {
      rtvs.push([RTV.setText(row[0]).setLinkUrl('http://example.com/' + row[0]).build()])
    })

  e.range.setRichTextValues(rtvs);
}
```

<sub>***NB: website was changed to `example.com` [due to stack guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-https-site-com-and-https-mysite-com-bloc).***</sub>

Comment: I was unable to make it work. Maybe I needed to change const link = 'http://example.com/' to something else. Regardless, if you have a chance I would appreciate it if you would copy and paste your solution to --- Extensions -> Apps Script in... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1usCU2UutcC9jchLlM-oBZVqgdfw_ERNFjOfrU_t5hkc/edit#gid=2100307022 ... and then let me know if it worked properly for you.

Comment: @Tiel can you explain what didn't work?

Comment: I copy and paste your solution to --- Extensions -> Apps Script, entered "cucumber" into B6, and it was not formatted. In other words, I only saw "cucumber" in plain text. Did you actually test your solution? If so, did it work for you.

Comment: [Yes of course I tested the solution.](https://i.imgur.com/Bh2Yv1s.gif)

Comment: I can see from your sheet link that you didn't add the script and your old script is still attached. Did *you* actually test the solution?

Comment: [And yes, pasting works too.](https://i.imgur.com/PGUraZ8.gif)

Comment: This assertion you made, "I can see from your sheet link that you didn't add the script and your old script is still attached." is false. I did add your script. However, because it didn't work I then removed your script because it failed to work properly. I don't want to paste one value at a time into the column. I want to paste multiple values at once into multiple cells. Please feel free to edit the spreadsheet as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I've edited my answer to work for multiple rows at a time

Comment: Moltes gràcies. Això va funcionar perfectament! Barcelona és una ciutat preciosa, per cert. Recordo haver escoltat dos vells parlant en un parc i pensar que havia oblidat completament tot el meu castellà. Més tard em vaig adonar que devien estar parlant català. --- ENGLISH TRANSLATION ---Thank you very much. That worked perfectly! Barcelona is a beautiful city, by the way. I remember overhearing two old men talking in a park and thinking I had completely forgotten all of my Spanish. Later I realized they must have been speaking Catalan.